# How to fetch the result of the cherrypy function?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch, cherrypy

I have the website hosted on local using XAMPP and the server written using cherrpy. I want to use cherrpy to return data and update the paragraph in the HTML page. Here's my code:
**index.html**

```
<p id="curtains_status" style="color: white;">a </p>
<script>
        curtains_submit.onclick = function() {
            response = await fetch("//127.0.0.1:8080/test");
            alert(await response.text);
    };
</script>
```

I created the paragraph to display its current state. I attached some code to it to (hopefully) fetch the data from the server.

**server.py**

```
import cherrypy

class Site(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def test(self):
        return "test"
cherrypy.quickstart(Site())
```

Here I defined the `test` function to `return` the 'test' so that I can alert it in `index.html` The problem is I don't get the `alert` executed.

Does anybody know what's the issue?

Comment: Is the request reaching the server? That `//` makes it relative to the protocol of the page. Also I think the proper await is `await response.text()` (function call)

Comment: @cyraxjoe It actually reaches it, I've tested it multiple times before. I'm just trying to let the server modify the website using .js